# Parsing JSON data from SQL Server table column

Tags: json, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-view

I am trying to parse JSON data from a table in SQL Server 2017. I have a view that returns this data:

```
| Debrief Name      |  Version  |   Answer Question        | Answer Options                                                                                                           |  
+-------------------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| Observer Report   |  7        |   Division:              | {"Options":[{"Display":"Domestic","Value":"Domestic"},{"Display":"International","Value":"International"}]}              |  
| Observer Report   |  7        |   Are you on reserve?    | {"Options":[{"Display":"Yes - Long Call Line","Value":"Yes"},{"Display":"No","Value":"No"}]}                             |  
| Observer Report   |  11       |   Crew Position:         | {"Options":[{"Display":"CA","Value":"CA"},{"Display":"RC","Value":"RC"},{"Display":"FO","Value":"FO"}]}                  |      
| Observer Report   |  11       |   Domicile:              | {"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"BOS","Value":"BOS"},{"Display":"CLT","Value":"CLT"}]}                           |  
| Training Debrief  |  12       |   TRAINING CREW POSITION | {"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"CA","Value":"CA"},{"Display":"FO","Value":"FO"}]}                               |  
| Training Debrief  |  12       |   AIRCRAFT               | {"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"777","Value":"777"},{"Display":"767","Value":"767"}]}                           |      
| Security Debrief  |  9        |   Aircraft Type          | {"Options":[{"Display":"MD-80","Value":"MD-80"},{"Display":"777","Value":"777"},{"Display":"767/757","Value":"767/757"}]}|      
| News Digest       |  2        |   Do you read Digest?    | {"Options":[{"Display":"Yes","Value":"Yes"},{"Display":"No","Value":"No"}]}                                              |
```

The `Debrief Name` column can have multiple records for same debrief name and `Version`. Also there are multiple versions for each debrief. And for each debrief name and version combination, there are set of `Answer Questions` and related `Answer Options`. Now the column `Answer Options` contain JSON record which I need to parse.

So my initial query that is something like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].<MY VIEW> 
WHERE [Debrief Name] = 'Observer Report' AND Version = 11
```

which would return below data:

```
| Debrief Name        |    Version   |  Answer Question      |   Answer Options                                                                                                | 
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Observer Report     |    11        |  Crew Position:       |   {"Options":[{"Display":"CA","Value":"CA"},{"Display":"RC","Value":"RC"}]}                                     | 
| Observer Report     |    11        |  Domicile:            |   {"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"BOS","Value":"BOS"},{"Display":"CLT","Value":"CLT"}]}                |     
| Observer Report     |    11        |  Fleet:               |   {"Options":[{"Display":"330","Value":"330"},{"Display":"320","Value":"320"}]}                                 | 
| Observer Report     |    11        |  Division:            |   {"Options":[{"Display":"Domestic","Value":"Domestic"},{"Display":"International","Value":"International"}]}   |     
| Observer Report     |    11        |  Are you on reserve?  |   {"Options":[{"Display":"Yes - Long Call Line","Value":"Yes - Long Call Line"},{"Display":"No","Value":"No"}]} |
```

Now from this returned result, for each `Answer Question` I need to parse the related `Answer Options` JSON data and extract the Value field for all the display attribute. So for example the JSON string in `Answer Options` for question "Are you on reserver?" looks like this:

```
"Options":[
    {
        "Display":"330",
        "Value":"330",
        "Selected":false
    },
    {
        "Display":"320",
        "Value":"320",
        "Selected":false
    },
    {
        "Display":"S80",
        "Value":"S80",
        "Selected":false
    }
]
```

So I need to extract "Value" fields and return something like an array with values {330, 320, 195}.

In conclusion I want to construct a query where when I provide the Debrief Name and VersionNumber, it returns me the `Answer Question` and all the `Answer Option` values.

I am thinking of using a stored procedure like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc 
    @DebriefName NVARCHAR(255), 
    @Version INT
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[myView] 
    WHERE [Debrief Name] = @DebriefName 
      AND Version = @Version
GO;
```

And then have another stored procedure that will capture this result from `myProc` and then do the JSON parsing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE parseJSON 
     @DebriefName NVARCHAR(255), 
     @Version INT
AS
    EXEC myProc @DebriefName, @Version; //Need to capture the result data in a temp table or something
    // Parse the JSON data for each question item in temp table
GO;
```

I am not an expert in SQL so not sure how to do this. I read about Json parsing in SQL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and feel like I can use that but not sure how to in my context.

Comment: Please don't post your data as an image; it isn't helpful the the volunteers you're asking help from. Post your data as **formatted** `text`, or as DDL and DML statement, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to parse JSON data in `Answer Options` column and extract the `Value` field, you may try with the following approach, using `OPENJSON()` and `STRING_AGG()`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
SET @json = N'{
   "Options": [
       {
       "Display": "330",
       "Value": "330",
       "Selected": false
       },
       {
       "Display": "320",
       "Value": "320",
       "Selected": false
       },   
       {
       "Display": "195",
       "Value": "195",
       "Selected": false
       }   
   ]
}'

SELECT STRING_AGG(x.[value], ', ') AS [Values]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Options') j
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(j.[value])) x
WHERE x.[key] = 'Value'
```

Output:

```
Values
330, 320, 195
```

If you want to build your statement using stored procedure, use this approach:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
   DebriefName nvarchar(100),
   Version int,
   AnswerQuestion nvarchar(1000),
   AnswerOptions nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO myTable
   (DebriefName, Version, AnswerQuestion, AnswerOptions)
VALUES
   (N'Observer Report',  7,  N'Division:'             , N'{"Options":[{"Display":"Domestic","Value":"Domestic"},{"Display":"International","Value":"International"}]}'),
   (N'Observer Report',  7,  N'Are you on reserve?'   , N'{"Options":[{"Display":"Yes - Long Call Line","Value":"Yes"},{"Display":"No","Value":"No"}]}'),
   (N'Observer Report',  11, N'Crew Position:'        , N'{"Options":[{"Display":"CA","Value":"CA"},{"Display":"RC","Value":"RC"},{"Display":"FO","Value":"FO"}]}'),
   (N'Observer Report',  11, N'Domicile:'             , N'{"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"BOS","Value":"BOS"},{"Display":"CLT","Value":"CLT"}]}'),
   (N'Training Debrief', 12, N'TRAINING CREW POSITION', N'{"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"CA","Value":"CA"},{"Display":"FO","Value":"FO"}]}'),
   (N'Training Debrief', 12, N'AIRCRAFT'              , N'{"VisibleLines":2,"Options":[{"Display":"777","Value":"777"},{"Display":"767","Value":"767"}]}'), 
   (N'Security Debrief', 9,  N'Aircraft Type'         , N'{"Options":[{"Display":"MD-80","Value":"MD-80"},{"Display":"777","Value":"777"},{"Display":"767/757","Value":"767/757"}]}'),
   (N'News Digest',      2,  N'Do you read Digest?'   , N'{"Options":[{"Display":"Yes","Value":"Yes"},{"Display":"No","Value":"No"}]}')

SELECT 
   t.AnswerQuestion,
   STRING_AGG(x.[value], ', ') AS [Values]
FROM myTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(t.AnswerOptions, '$.Options')) j
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(j.[value])) x
WHERE 
   DebriefName = N'Observer Report' AND
   t.Version = 11 AND
   x.[key] = 'Value'
GROUP BY 
   t.DebriefName,
   t.Version,
   t.AnswerQuestion
```

Output:

```
AnswerQuestion  Values
Crew Position:  CA, RC, FO
Domicile:       BOS, CLT
```